# How do I fix Firestore Flutter dependencies error?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I keep getting the same error on firebase versions
This is the YAML:

```
 provider: ^4.3.3
  firebase_database: ^4.4.0
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.4.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.7+1
  cloud_functions: ^0.9.0
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.14
```

How do I handle this?.
Every time i change one of the versions, another one get error.

Comment: The actual error is
"Because firebase_database 4.4.0 depends on firebase_core ^0.5.3 and no versions of firebase_database match >4.4.0 <5.0.0, firebase_database ^4.4.0 requires firebase_core ^0.5.3.
So, because teste depends on both firebase_database ^4.4.0 and firebase_core ^0.7.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because teste depends on both firebase_database ^4.4.0 and firebase_core ^0.7.0, version solving failed.)"

Comment: Use the latest dependencies, the errors will go away.

Comment: use firebase_database: any or just firebase_database:

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest dependencies, the errors will go away. Update them in your `pubspec.yaml` file.